# Postfix "Connection timed out"

Tags: postfix, smtp

I try to send a few emails, but postfix send only 3 emails every 10-20 min. After that postfix sends 3 emails, I get the error: "Connection timed out".

**mail.log:**

```
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/pickup[1810]: 2B7FF4265D: uid=1000 from=<ubuntu>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/cleanup[2142]: 2B7FF4265D: message-id=<20160104101639.2B7FF4265D@mail.example.biz>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 2B7FF4265D: from=<ubuntu@mail.example.biz>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/pickup[1810]: 2DCEF41D30: uid=1000 from=<ubuntu>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/cleanup[2142]: 2DCEF41D30: message-id=<20160104101639.2DCEF41D30@mail.example.biz>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 2DCEF41D30: from=<ubuntu@mail.example.biz>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/pickup[1810]: 3166642668: uid=1000 from=<ubuntu>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/cleanup[2142]: 3166642668: message-id=<20160104101639.3166642668@mail.example.biz>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 3166642668: from=<ubuntu@mail.example.biz>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/pickup[1810]: 3202442665: uid=1000 from=<ubuntu>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/cleanup[2142]: 3202442665: message-id=<20160104101639.3202442665@mail.example.biz>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 3202442665: from=<ubuntu@mail.example.biz>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/pickup[1810]: 34D834266C: uid=1000 from=<ubuntu>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/cleanup[2142]: 34D834266C: message-id=<20160104101639.34D834266C@mail.example.biz>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 34D834266C: from=<ubuntu@mail.example.biz>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/pickup[1810]: 371B142705: uid=1000 from=<ubuntu>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/cleanup[2142]: 371B142705: message-id=<20160104101639.371B142705@mail.example.biz>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 371B142705: from=<ubuntu@mail.example.biz>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/pickup[1810]: 38C6242706: uid=1000 from=<ubuntu>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/cleanup[2142]: 38C6242706: message-id=<20160104101639.38C6242706@mail.example.biz>
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 38C6242706: from=<ubuntu@mail.example.biz>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/smtp[2151]: 2DCEF41D30: to=<email.example@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.184.26]:25, delay=0.39, delays=0.01/0.01/0.07/0.31, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1451902596 j5si104274568wmj.19 - gsmtp)
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 2DCEF41D30: removed
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/smtp[2157]: 3166642668: to=<email.example@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.184.26]:25, delay=0.38, delays=0.01/0/0.06/0.31, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1451902596 n8si144057102wjy.101 - gsmtp)
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 3166642668: removed
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/smtp[2149]: 2B7FF4265D: to=<email.example@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.184.26]:25, delay=0.42, delays=0.01/0.01/0.07/0.33, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1451902596 cf10si144013024wjc.167 - gsmtp)
Jan  4 12:16:39 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 2B7FF4265D: removed
Jan  4 12:17:09 mail postfix/smtp[2158]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.184.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:17:09 mail postfix/smtp[2164]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.184.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:17:09 mail postfix/smtp[2151]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.184.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:17:09 mail postfix/smtp[2169]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.184.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:17:39 mail postfix/smtp[2164]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.164.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:17:39 mail postfix/smtp[2158]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.164.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:17:39 mail postfix/smtp[2151]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.164.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:17:39 mail postfix/smtp[2169]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.164.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:18:09 mail postfix/smtp[2164]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.189.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:18:09 mail postfix/smtp[2158]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.189.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:18:09 mail postfix/smtp[2169]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.189.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:18:09 mail postfix/smtp[2151]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.189.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:18:39 mail postfix/smtp[2158]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.189.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:18:39 mail postfix/smtp[2164]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.189.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:18:39 mail postfix/smtp[2151]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.189.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:18:39 mail postfix/smtp[2169]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.189.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:19:09 mail postfix/smtp[2164]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:19:09 mail postfix/smtp[2158]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:19:09 mail postfix/smtp[2164]: 34D834266C: to=<email.example@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=150, delays=0.01/0/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Jan  4 12:19:09 mail postfix/smtp[2158]: 3202442665: to=<email.example@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=150, delays=0/0.01/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Jan  4 12:19:09 mail postfix/smtp[2169]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:19:09 mail postfix/smtp[2151]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:19:09 mail postfix/smtp[2169]: 38C6242706: to=<email.example@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=151, delays=0/0.34/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Jan  4 12:19:09 mail postfix/smtp[2151]: 371B142705: to=<email.example@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=151, delays=0/0.35/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.25.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Jan  4 12:22:29 mail postfix/scache[2170]: statistics: start interval Jan  4 12:16:39
Jan  4 12:22:29 mail postfix/scache[2170]: statistics: domain lookup hits=0 miss=2 success=0%
Jan  4 12:22:29 mail postfix/scache[2170]: statistics: address lookup hits=0 miss=10 success=0%
Jan  4 12:27:01 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 34D834266C: from=<ubuntu@mail.example.biz>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  4 12:27:01 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 3202442665: from=<ubuntu@mail.example.biz>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  4 12:27:01 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 38C6242706: from=<ubuntu@mail.example.biz>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  4 12:27:01 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 371B142705: from=<ubuntu@mail.example.biz>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  4 12:27:02 mail postfix/smtp[2200]: 3202442665: to=<email.example@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.26]:25, delay=623, delays=623/0.01/0.12/0.23, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1451903219 b8si144255671wjx.62 - gsmtp)
Jan  4 12:27:02 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 3202442665: removed
Jan  4 12:27:02 mail postfix/smtp[2201]: 38C6242706: to=<email.example@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.26]:25, delay=623, delays=623/0.01/0.13/0.25, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1451903219 v126si130607326wmg.9 - gsmtp)
Jan  4 12:27:02 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 38C6242706: removed
Jan  4 12:27:02 mail postfix/smtp[2199]: 34D834266C: to=<email.example@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.26]:25, delay=623, delays=623/0.01/0.13/0.25, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1451903219 s8si117915607wmf.111 - gsmtp)
Jan  4 12:27:02 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 34D834266C: removed
Jan  4 12:27:31 mail postfix/smtp[2202]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:28:01 mail postfix/smtp[2202]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:28:31 mail postfix/smtp[2202]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:29:01 mail postfix/smtp[2202]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.72.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:29:25 mail postfix/postqueue[2204]: fatal: usage: postqueue -f | postqueue -i queueid | postqueue -p | postqueue -s site
Jan  4 12:29:32 mail postfix/smtp[2202]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.72.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  4 12:29:32 mail postfix/smtp[2202]: 371B142705: to=<email.example@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=773, delays=623/0.01/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.72.27]:25: Connection timed out)
Jan  4 12:45:05 mail postfix/postqueue[2228]: fatal: usage: postqueue -f | postqueue -i queueid | postqueue -p | postqueue -s site
Jan  4 12:47:01 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 371B142705: from=<ubuntu@mail.example.biz>, size=4514, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  4 12:47:02 mail postfix/smtp[2231]: 371B142705: to=<email.example@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.26]:25, delay=1823, delays=1822/0.01/0.16/0.22, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1451904418 uu9si144388739wjc.63 - gsmtp)
Jan  4 12:47:02 mail postfix/qmgr[19597]: 371B142705: removed
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Is there a firewall somewhere which block the connections ?

Comment: I use the AWS (Amazon Web Services), but in my "Security group" of AWS all required ports are open.
[screenshot](http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0000/0118/16502/160104/2f2b633d21.jpg)

Comment: I think you should see in outbound, as your server try to connect to gmail

Comment: In outbound all traffic is open.

Comment: Are you perhaps running into the limit that AWS puts upon sending emails? (As noted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311747/aws-ec2-email-sending-limit-when-using-third-party-smtp-server)
You might want to consider using their Simple Email Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps running into the limit that AWS puts upon sending emails? (As noted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311747/aws-ec2-email-sending-limit-when-using-third-party-smtp-server).

You might want to consider using their Simple Email Service.